# Inextendible timelike worldline with finite proper time in Minkowski space?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration

would anybody be able to give me an example of a timelike worldline in Minkowski spacetime which is inextendible (so will run off to infinity) and has a finite length? I'm thinking it will be something that looks like hyperbolic motion, but that doesn't have a fixed acceleration?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! I'm not sure why somebody downvoted the question. Maybe they thought it was homework? Yes, I think examples like this can be constructed. The proper acceleration has to increase. Have you tried writing down examples and seeing if you can integrate the proper time? I'm not sure, but IIRC there may be an example like this in the classic paper by Geroch, "What is a singularity in general relativity?," Ann Phys 48 (1968) 526.

Comment: Thanks Ben! And thank you for pointing me in the right direction :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example : take a timelike curve with unbounded acceleration in finite time. To do this, consider a curve with the acceleration

$$\|\ddot\gamma(\tau)\| = \alpha(\tau)^2$$

But still timelike :

$$\|\dot\gamma(\tau)\| = -1$$

So the equations for it are

\begin{eqnarray}
\ddot{x}^2(\tau) - \ddot{t}^2(\tau) &=& \alpha(\tau)^2\\
\dot{x}^2(\tau) - \dot{t}^2(\tau) &=& -1
\end{eqnarray}

Switching to null coordinates, this gives us

\begin{eqnarray}
\ddot{u}(\tau) \ddot{v}(\tau) &=& \alpha(\tau)^2\\
\dot{u}(\tau)\dot{v}(\tau)  &=& -1
\end{eqnarray}

This means that $\dot{u} = -\dot{v}^{-1}$, which gives us the relation

$$\left(\frac{\ddot{v}}{\dot{v}}\right)^2 = \alpha(\tau)^2$$

There's a few possible solutions to this (they'll correspond to various time and space orientation of the curve), but we'll pick the one where everything is positive,

$$\ddot{v}  - \alpha(\tau)\dot{v} = 0$$

This is a fairly simple system to solve, with solution

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot v(\tau) &=& A \exp({\int_1^{\tau} \alpha(\xi) d\xi})\\
\dot u(\tau) &=& A^{-1} \exp({-\int_1^{\tau} \alpha(\xi) d\xi})
\end{eqnarray}

or, in Cartesian coordinates,

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot t(\tau) &=& \sinh(\int_1^{\tau} \alpha(\xi) d\xi)\\
\dot x(\tau) &=& \cosh(\int_1^{\tau} \alpha(\xi) d\xi)
\end{eqnarray}

A very simple unbounded acceleration in finite time is to simply pick $\alpha = \tan(\tau)$, which will diverge for $\tau = \pi/2$. This gives us

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot t(\tau) &=& \sinh(-\ln(\cos(\tau)))\\
\dot x(\tau) &=& \cosh(-\ln(\cos(\tau)))
\end{eqnarray}

The time coordinate can be calculated explicitely :

\begin{eqnarray}
t(\tau) &=& \int \sinh(-\ln(\cos(\tau))) d\tau \\
&=& \frac 12 (- \sin (\tau) - \ln( \cos(t/2) - \sin(t/2) )) + \ln( \cos(t/2) + \sin(t/2) )
\end{eqnarray}

which tends to $-\ln(0) / 2$ at $\tau = \pm \pi/2$.

This curve has no endpoint. It can be shown by considering that if it had an endpoint ending at $\tau_b$, there would be a neighbourgood where $\gamma(\tau_b + d\tau)$ belongs to. Just make some arbitrarily small neighbourhood around that point $(t_a, t_b) \times (x_a, x_b)$. Since $t(\tau_b)$ is strictly increasing and divergent, there can be no extension of that curve.

The total proper time of the curve is just $\pi$ then.

Comment: Thank you Slereah! I got a lot out of this detailed answer, this is just what I was looking for. You make it look easy ;)